# Service for checking Dart/Flutter code like Codebeat or Codacy?

Tags: flutter, dart, static-analysis, code-analysis, dart-analyzer

Are there any services for cloud Dart/Flutter code checking like Codebeat or Codacy?

Comment: I think Sonarqube has a Flutter plugin. But I haven't tried it myself.